# PHP V8 JS Not executing however page doesn't break and no errors are shown

Tags: javascript, php, v8

I've tried installing the V8 Engine for PHP to run JavaScript inside PHP.
I followed this tutorial here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVGDo7h-rEc

Previoulsy when I didnt have the package installed I received an error when calling v8 in PHP.
After following the directions in the video; no errors are occuring and the JavaScript isnt being executed.

Heres the PHP Code im using:

```
$v8 = new V8Js();
echo $v8->executeString(1 + 1);
```

Comment: Haven't used V8Js yet but taken from the function name ["executeString()"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/v8js.executestring.php) I would expect it to accept a string instead of integers and mathematical symbols. What does `$v8->executeString("1+1");` return?

Comment: Nothing aswell.